# Bonus troops from controlling continents and trading cards for troops in Risk

Tags: risk

I have a few questions on the lovely game :-

1. In my current turn I've conquered a continent and keep it conquered for the following 3 turns. Do I get bonus troops in every turn that I have conquered it in ?
2. If I am trading cards for troops, and I have a territory on the face of the card too. Do I still get my base troops that we get ( the whole count and divide by 3 ones )

Answer (score 6):

Per the [rules](https://www.hasbro.com/common/instruct/risk.pdf)

1. You gain bonus troops for each of your turns you start while in control of the continent

> In  addition,  at  the  beginning  of  your  turn  you  will  receive
>   armies  for  each  continent  you  control.

2. Yes, you get the base count, plus any continent bonus, plus the value of the cards you trade in, plus 2 bonus troops for trading in a territory card you occupy.

> At the 
>   beginning of each turn, calculate how many new armies you’ll add to your territories based on ...
>
> 1. The  number  of  territories  you  occupy;
> 2. The  value  of  the  continents  you  control;
> 3. The value of the matched sets of RISK cards you trade in;
> 4. The  specific  territory  pictured  on  a  traded-in  card.